# In ArcMap, why does "Reclassify Raster" tool provide different result than when reclassifying the original raster symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, reclassify

I was reviewing the results of a string of tools I created in ModelBuilder and I noticed that the results seemed off. I was masking multiple rasters to the same boundary, then reclassifying those rasters to the same scale - quintiles with new values from 1 to 5.
[image: Overview of the model I created]

When I pull up the reclassify tool in the ModelBuilder I see a reclassification scheme such as the following:

[image: Reclassification of raster in model]

But when taking the same, original raster in the table of contents and reclassifying the symbology, I see the following result:

[image]

If you look closely at those screenshots, you will notice that the breaks for each quintile are different. Does anyone know why the ranges for each quintile are different?

I am confused as to why there would be a difference seeing as I used the same raster, and same quintile classification scheme. I am 100% sure I used the same rasters and that I did not cross any streams in the model I built.